# Docker volume bind results in IIS 401.3 error

Tags: php, docker, iis, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to setup a local development environment with IIS for hosting and I get some wierd behaviour. The initial load of the website works, but a few refreshes results in 401.3. After like 30 seconds I can then refresh the page again and it works. Also, URL's like localhost does not work and goes straight to 401.3 and I have to use localhost/index.php for example.

If I instead uses the command COPY ./data C:\inetpub\wwwroot the website works flawlesly. I also checked the access control list and was wondering if that was the issue. Using the volume bind via docker-compose results in different ACL than using COPY command in the Dockerfile. The files and folders from the volume cannot be changed as Docker does not allow to change ACL on files and folders that are part of the volume.

I have also tried using different application pool and website than the default ones, but the result is the same.

I am currently using the base windows/servercore:ltsc2019 image and are using the following setup for IIS:

```
RUN powershell -Command `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server, Web-Http-Redirect, Web-Http-Tracing, Web-Dyn-Compression, Web-Windows-Auth, Web-Asp, NET-Framework-45-ASPNET, NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45, Web-Asp-Net45; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.10/ServiceMonitor.exe" -OutFile "C:\ServiceMonitor.exe"

RUN dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /All && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Either'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].instanceMaxRequests:10000 && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC',value='C:\PHP'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:defaultDocument /enabled:true /+files.[value='index.php'] && `
    setx PATH /M %PATH%;C:\PHP && `
    setx PHP /M "C:\PHP" && `
    del C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /Q
```

The docker-compose file consits of a single service with a volume defined as:

```
volumes:
    -  type: bind
       source: ./data
       target: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Comment: Microsoft ended its own support for PHP on IIS/Windows, so now you rely on “the PHP community” or yourself. If possible, use a Linux image and you might find much more people with the knowledge to help you out.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 401.3 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: It does not seem to be a PHP issue. As stated, the application works great without the use of Docker volumes. It is only when I am using volumes that I get the 401.3 error. I have tested using Lunix with Apache and Nginx and it works, also with Windows and Apache. 

In regards to the tracing, it does not seem to log any more detailes than written in the post. Only the file requested, IP, browser type and error (E.g. 401 3 5 1) is displayed in the logs. The folder \FailedReqLogFiles however, is empty.

Comment: For failed request tracking, there is an option to enable it on the right side of the website interface. that's my guess about tracking not working.